# Is it possible to unset multiple git config values in a single call to git, rather than one by one?

Tags: git

I need to automate unsetting a lot of aliases, diff, difftool, merge, mergetool settings in the global git config file.

Right now I am calling `git config --global --unset` for each and every one of them and it is kind of slow. Well, relatively - takes about 3 seconds.

But I am curious - is there a way to call git only once in some kind of a batch mode to unset all of them in one go? I can see there is `--unset-all` option, but it seems to work on a single config setting having multiple values. Or am I missing anything?

Comment: `--unset-all`, yes, but then use a regexp to match each candidate of your list, maybe just something like `(setting1|setting2|setting3)`

Comment: The help for config contains this line: `remove all matches: name [value-regex]`. I do not understand what should be `name` in the case of many disparate settings.

Comment: Like I tried to explain (sorry if unclear), it would then be `(name1|name2|name3)` if you want to get rid of these three example names (or any other matching any of these three strings)

Comment: `--unset-all` can remove many values but I don't believe it can remove many keys.

Comment: @phd - that is my feeling exactly. RomainValeri - have you actually tried your suggestion?

Comment: @mark I'm experimenting at the moment. Frustrating but it seems you guys are right, sorry for the confusion on my part.

Answer (score 3):

For bulk work, just edit the config file. It's a common and simple format.

Comment: Does not answer my question,I specifically mention automation.

Comment: I'd recommend switching to an editor you can automate, then.

Comment: @jthill : factual :D

Comment: @mark you can find the *config* file in the project folder (local: *{root}/.git/config*}. And edit it by text editor (like notepad++).    > *note*: global config file is { *C:\Users\username\.gitconfig* }  in Windows system.

Answer (score 1):

just edit the *config* file of Git by shell.

we can see [the location of Git config file](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES) :

[image: Location of Windows Git Config Files]
[image: Location of Linux Git Config Files]

For more details you can see this [blog](https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/Where-system-global-and-local-Windows-Git-config-files-are-saved)

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.